# Find all tangent lines to the graph of $\frac{1}{\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}$ that are parallel to the line x = y = z

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, tangent-line

Find all tangent lines to the graph of $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}$ that are parallel to the line $x = y = z$

Edit: Some additional information:

That is everything I was given in the file with the additional problems for my Calculus 2 course.

When I asked the lecturer about the problem, he said that I should consider substituting x and y with something of t, but that advice was given a week ago and I've already forgotten all the details.

Before I stuck with the problem, I figured out the direction of the partial derivatives which is $u = (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, \frac{\sqrt 2}{2})$, the gradient (and partial derivatives) $\nabla f(x,y) = (\frac{-x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}},\frac{-y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}})$, that all partial derivatives in the direction of $u$ should have the value of the slope of the line $x = y = z$ which, I believe, is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$ and that I need to find all points on the graph of $f(x,y)$ that give such slope and express them with a set builder and with know how to find any of those points I can make a set builder for all the lines that are tangent to the graph and are parallel to the line.

Comment: Please provide more context to your question and include the attempts you have done. You might consider: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: I've tried to add some more information and what I've already done.Hope that can help. However, the initial text is how the problem was stated in the additional problems list for my Calculus 2 course and I felt like I had got nowhere and all that little progress that I had made was as useless as it gets,